# OSError with rosbridge_server on ROS2 Foxy Windows 10

Tags: ros2, rosbridge, windows10, ros-foxy, rosbridge-server

I have installed ROS 2 Foxy on Windows 10 using [this guide](https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/SetupRos2.html). I am attempting to connect to Foxglove Studio over rosbridge. To do this I built the `rosbridge_server` package from `rosbride_suite` GitHub.

I run `rosbridge_server` using the following command:

```
ros2 launch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket_launch.xml
```

The above command throws the following error:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below C:\Users\AIRL\.ros\log\2023-10-19-10-49-56-361940-DESKTOP-B6E3S8F-7772
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [rosbridge_websocket.PY-1]: exception occurred while executing process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\launch\actions\execute_process.py", line 723, in __execute_process
    transport, self._subprocess_protocol = await async_execute_process(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\osrf_pycommon\process_utils\async_execute_process_asyncio\impl.py", line 142, in async_execute_process
    transport, protocol = yield from _async_execute_process_nopty(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\osrf_pycommon\process_utils\async_execute_process_asyncio\impl.py", line 46, in _async_execute_process_nopty
    transport, protocol = yield from loop.subprocess_exec(
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
  File "asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
  File "asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

[ERROR] [rosapi_node.PY-2]: exception occurred while executing process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\launch\actions\execute_process.py", line 723, in __execute_process
    transport, self._subprocess_protocol = await async_execute_process(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\osrf_pycommon\process_utils\async_execute_process_asyncio\impl.py", line 142, in async_execute_process
    transport, protocol = yield from _async_execute_process_nopty(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\osrf_pycommon\process_utils\async_execute_process_asyncio\impl.py", line 46, in _async_execute_process_nopty
    transport, protocol = yield from loop.subprocess_exec(
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
  File "asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
  File "asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What does this error message mean, and how do I resolve this error?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! It seems that the `rosbridge_server` package is not installed correctly such as missing dependencies. Can you please removed the existing `rosbridge_server` package and install it from `apt` by `sudo apt install ros-foxy-rosbridge-suite`. You can look at the detailed steps at [this blog post](https://zenn.dev/toitoy8/articles/220514_py-roslibpy_rosbridge). Please translate the page as per your convenience.

Comment: Hello @ravi thank you for the reply. The blog post uses WSL to run ROS2, whereas my application needs ROS2 to run natively on windows. Windows uses chocolatey package manager, which does not have rosbridge packages.